# PAF installation for windows 7

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

I am trying to install PAF in windows 7 ,but facing error in the system. Is there a separate bat file to install PAF for windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

**No**, It is not possible to install PAF for windows 7, PAF supports only for windows 10 and higher versions.